# How to change the "Statement Parameter Limit" of the JDBC Producer setting?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spotfire

A while ago my team found an exception that occurs every time the user selects a lot of data points in a Map Chart (our marking limit was set to a really high number - 2million). That throws an exception that we saw in the Monitoring section of the Spotfire Admin panel:

> The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a
>   maximum of 2100 parameters

I was searching only and found that this is because of a limitation of the database we are using - Microsoft SQL Server. I also found that there is a way to tell Spotfire to split the query into multiple batches when the query parameters contain more than 2100 parameters. According to a page on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/streamsets.com/forum/#!msg/sdc-user/zoWW5TVOE3k/4wbDT4MXAwAJ) we need to set the "Statement Parameter Limit" in the JDBC producer to a value < 2100. The problem is, I don't know where I am supposed to make that change. Am I supposed to change a config file on the Spotfire Server? If that is the case, where I can find that config file?

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server connector in my Spotfire analysis file